# Adding two columns and subtract from another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three columns in my database table, namely `owed`, `paid` and `writeoff`. I need to calculate the total outstanding after summing up `paid` and `writeoff` and subtract that from `owed`.

```
owed-(paid+writeoff)
```

Comment: Pretty simple select statement what do you need help with?  you have the heart of it already.  Just need SELECT... FROM...

Comment: For any NULLable column you need to apply `COALESCE(col,0)` to avoid NULL results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
  sum(t.owed - (t.paid + t.writeoff)) AS result
from 
  {your_table} t
```